# Detect subset item in One looping array

Tags: php, laravel, knapsack-problem

I have some task to detecting is there any items that subset from the next item which's come from next looping one array, this is for unset the item's from that's array which's the item is subset from the next item's in that's array.

**This is my array come from loop :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Sabrino
                    [duration] => 7
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Building Relation Query
                    [duration] => 3
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Building Relation Query
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Doing Looping
                    [duration] => 1
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Building Relation Query
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Introduction To Laravel
                    [duration] => 1
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Building Relation Query
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Learn Function
                    [duration] => 1
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Building Relation Query
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => improve something
                    [duration] => 1
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Make View Controller and Index
                    [duration] => 3
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Make View Controller and Index
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Doing Looping
                    [duration] => 1
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Pr pr pr
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Make View Controller and Index
                    [duration] => 3
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Introduction To Laravel
                    [duration] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

and i use this code for detecting the subset :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($sugesti); ++$i) {
    if (!array_diff($sugesti[$i], $sugesti[$i + 1])) {
        unset($sugesti[$i]);
    }
}
```

I want to remove the array which's subset from the next array

Comment: It is hard to follow what you are trying to do. Maybe if you provide the example above outputted as you want it we can better understand what you are looking for,

Comment: I want to show the only unique items in that array

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$existing = [];

foreach ($sugesti as $key => $sugest) {
    foreach ($sugest as $key2 => $sug {
        if (in_array($sug->name, $existing)) {
            unset($sugesti[$key][$key2];
            continue;
        }
        $existing[] = $sug->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that true sintaks for in_array?

Comment: Nicely picked up. Sorry I had to go do something and then come back part way through. I have updated the example.

Comment: the result is still wrong from that I want, if i use that sintaks, it give an empty array, but if remove the key2 in unset function, it also removed the first element which's that unique not repeatly show in array, and there is still duplicate items in the array

Comment: @sab896 I am sorry but you will need to either be more clear as to what you want or adjust the code to meet your needs.